# Simplify (W + Y) (W' + X' + Y) (X' + Y' + Z')

Tags: boolean-algebra

Okay, so I started from 
*( (W + Y + Z')' (W' + X' + Y)' (X' + Y' + Z')' (W + Y + Z)' )'*

then simplified further to:

*( W'Y'Z + WXY' + XYZ + W'Y'Z' )'*

then:

*(W + Y + Z')(W' + X' + Y)(X' + Y' + Z')(W + Y + Z)*

to:

*(W + Y)(W' + X' + Y)(X' + Y' + Z')*

The answer is: *(W + Y)(X' + Y)(X' + Z')*.

How do I go from what I currently have to the answer? I've tried breaking up the other two expressions to *(W' + X')(W' + Y)* and played around like that, but to no avail. What rule am I not using correctly?

Thanks

Comment: This part is wrong: $( W'Y'Z + WXY' + XYZ + W'Y'Z' )'$, it should be like this: $( (W'Y'Z)(WXY')(XYZ)(W'Y'Z'))'$ which is equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from *(W + Y)(W' + X' + Y)(X' + Y' + Z')* (you have already solved till this point)

let *Y=A, B=W* and *C=(W'+X')* for next step using *(A+B)(A+C)=(A+BC)*;

*=(Y+W(W'+X')) (X' + Y' + Z')*

*=(Y+WW'+WX')(X' + Y' + Z')* //*WW'=0*

*=(Y+WX')(X' + Y' + Z')*  //simplified by removing *WW'=0*

*=(Y+W)(Y+X')(X' + Y' + Z')* // used *(A+B)(A+C)=A+BC*

*=(W+Y)(X'+Y(Y'+Z'))* // used *(A+B)(A+C)=A+BC*

*=(W+Y)(X'+YY'+YZ')*

*=(W+Y)(X'+YZ')*

*=(W+Y)(X'+Y)(X'+Z')*=Answer

Comment: Jesus, didn't think I was so far from solving it O.O
Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 1):

$((W+Y+Z')'(W'+X'+Y)'(X'+Y'+Z')'(W+Y+Z)')'=(W+Y+Z')+(W'+X'+Y)+(X'+Y'+Z')+(W+Y+Z)=W'+W+X'+Y'+Y+Z'+Z=1$

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

**Generalized Reduction**

$(P+Q)(P+Q'+R)=(P+Q)(P+R)$

With that:

$(W+Y)(W'+X'+Y)(X'+Y'+Z')=$

$(W+Y)(X'+Y)(X'+Y'+Z')=$

$(W+Y)(X'+Y)(X'+Z')$